# How to pass ReactJS props properly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to pass some values using `props` in `ReactJS` but, values are not passing not showing.

This is my `html` for the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <title>React JS</title> 
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="main.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my `main.jsx` which renders a class named `AppContainer` component

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import AppContainer from './AppContainer';

render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is my `AppContainer.jsx` which renders `Users.jsx` component

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Users from './Users';

export default class AppContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [{id: Date.now(), name: 'John'}]
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <Users users={this.state.users}/>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

And this is my `Users.jsx` class which renders `User.jsx` component

```
'user strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import User from './User';

export default class Users extends Component{
    static get propTypes(){
        return {
            //validate users must be an array
            users: PropTypes.array
        }
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            man: this.props
        }
    }

    render(){
        //get users from props 
        const {users} = this.state.man;

        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            users.map((user) => {
                                return <User key={user.id} user={user}  />
                            })                       
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my `User.jsx` where I guess values are not passing properly to the `props`

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class User extends Component{   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: this.props
        }
    }

    render(){        
        return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.state.user.id}</td> 
                    <td>{this.state.user.name}</td>                
                </tr>            
        );
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of how my output looks like. (In outputs, the `id` and the `name` is not shown, only the `<th>` are shown as below:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone please tell me where I have done wrong? Thank you!

Comment: A good way to debug is to use console.log and log the objects in each component to see what it looks like being passed around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving your props to state, which is an object, doing `this.state.user.name` becomes undefined, do

Given `props` like `key="34" user="objUser"`

When you say `user = this.props`, user now becomes `{key: 34, user: objUser}`, to access those properties you can't `user.name`, you'll need to access user object, by doing `user.user.name`, because you have assigned the whole props object to `user`.

```
export default class User extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        user: this.props.user
     }
   }
  // rest of the code
 }
```

do the same in `<Users />`

```
export default class Users extends Component{
    static get propTypes(){
        return {
           //validate users must be an array
           users: PropTypes.array
        }
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
          man: this.props.users
        }
    }
   // rest of the code
  }
```

**Note**

You don't really need to save the values in state, if the value is not going to change. You can access the value via props directly. like

```
render() {
   const user =  this.props.user
   const man = this.props.man
   // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed 2 things :

```
'user strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import User from './User';

export default class Users extends Component{
    static get propTypes(){
    return {
        //validate users must be an array
        users: PropTypes.array
    }
}

constructor(props){
    super(props);
//remove here
}

render(){
    //get users from props 
//change here
    const {users} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        users.map((user) => {
                            return <User key={user.id} user={user}  />
                        })                       
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```